# Having issues translating a regex behavior from python to AWK

Tags: python, regex, awk

I'm trying to do something like the following (written on python) but on awk but having issues getting it to work

```
new_row=re.sub(r'(.)\1{5,}', r'\1', row)
```

Basically I want to be able to replace instances of repeating consecutive characters (5 or more) into just one.  I need to be able to set how many instances of a single character trigger the regex but I'm having issues figuring out how to get it done in awk.

Comment: In awk, are you using `gsub`? It does not support replacement backreferences. Use `gensub` if available.

Comment: I was trying to use gensub but I'm unable to do the translation to the gensub syntax properly

Comment: So, post what you tried and let know.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to do it faster with perl, but thanks

Comment: Please add that Perl code to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I added it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ended up not needing awk and did it using perl.  The regex is pretty much identical.  I have a var called $tmp_fieldwhich has current string I want to edit:

`($tmp_field) =~ s/(.)\1{5,}/\1/g`

That was it, thank you all

Comment: You made a common mistake. Replacement backreferences are `$1`, not `\1`. Perl is not `sed`.